# Bridging between to different subnets

Tags: networking, server

I'm new to ubuntu server (22.04). I have my isp router 192.168.1.1 connected to my ubuntu server via ethernet. I also have my iot devices on a linksys router (10.208.1.x). the linksys router (WAN 192.168.1.54, LAN 10.208.1.1) is connect via ethernet to the isp router. My question is can I have the server able to communicate to the linksys router and if so how do I do that. Hope someone can help.

Comment: This is more a networking question then Ubuntu problem. One solution is to put everything in the same subnet. Or configure the Linksys router to forward the needed ports to the iot devices.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** As @user68186 noted, your question doesn't appear to be related to the Ubuntu OS. You may be better served over on the [Network Engineering StackExchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=subnet+bridging).

Comment: I followed your advice and place everything under the same subnet. Much easier. Thanks

Comment: try "route add" command